# Undertanding the performance of replication in distributed storage

Tags: performance, storage, drbd

I have a bit of a struggle understanding the performance when using replication in distributed storage solutions (Linstor/DRBD in my case).

I have 3 storage nodes, 10 NVMe each. Each NVMe has a write performance of 200k IOPS, so the total IOPS of one storage node is 2M. When I use replication 1x, the total write performance is as expected, about ~1M8 on each storage node. But when I use replication 3x, the write performance on each node is stuck at 800k, which means the physical NVMes is not accelerated enough. I have checked the CPU, memory, and network, but they still have plenty of resources.

So maybe there is a bottleneck in somewhere else or this is a normal situation when using replication?

Comment: Typically in a replicated system like this, writes are synchronous but reads are parallel and independent.   In this case, your max write speed would be the speed of the slowest ssds plus the network latency.  A cheap switch might not be able to handle the full bandwidth of the parallel writes from more than two machines.